# How to disable DTD processing to prevent XXE attack in MSSOAP.SOAPClinet30 in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, soap-client, xxe

I am using MSSOAP.SOAPClinet30 to make SOAP Web service requests using Classic ASP and which returns XML and it has an external entity which it processes.

```
  SET objSoapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
        objSoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
        Call objSoapClient.mssoapinit("URL","Method")
        If Len(base64str & "") > 0 Then
          strOutput = objSoapClient.ParseDocNew("Data","filename.docx",base64str,"","","","")
        End If
```

Suppose, The web service method return below XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [    
    <!ENTITY win SYSTEM “c:\windows\win.ini">
]>
<doc>
    &win;
</doc>
```

In this case, It processes external entity and Disclosure information.

so, Is there any way to prevent DTD processing by using "MSSOAP.SoapClient30" or any other relevant component which I can use in Classic ASP.